# Problema con Fetch en Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, fetch, powershell

Estoy conociendo Node.js y al comenzar la parte de **FETCH**, tengo este error al ejecutar **nodemon index**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
const fetch = import("node-fetch");

fetch("http://polls.apiblueprint.org/parks?status=Open")
    .then((respuesta) => {
        return respuesta.json()
    }).then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    })
```

Parece que el fetch no es reconocido. He probado algunas variantes que encontré en la web, como por ejemplo:

`global.fetch = require("node-fetch");`

o **npm install --save cross-fetch**

`import fetch from 'cross-fetch';`

pero el resultado es el mismo.

Tampoco me reconoce el `const fetch = require("node-fetch");`, saliendome este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy haciendo mal?... La version de node es: 16.9.1 (Estaba en el 14, y lo actualice)**

He instalado:

**npm init -y**

**npm install nodemon**

**npm install node-fetch**

Mis carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si acabas de instalar la última versión de `node-fetch` entones no la puedes usar así. La [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) te pide que hagas esto:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Si el problema es que estás usando node sin transpilar con Babel entonces tienes que usar la carga dinámica de la librería como lo indica la documentación:

```
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
```

La otra opción es quedarte con la versión 2 de node-fetch.

Comment: Excelente, aunque de ese modo, tengo el error: " Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Ya encontré la solución al último mensaje. Se soluciona añadiendo                          
"type": "module" en el package.json...

Comment: Apostaría a que estás usando node sin BabelJS. De ser así entonces el problema es que la versión de fetch ya no se puede usar directamente sin un transpilador. Tienes 2 opciones: usar la versión 2 o hacer un import dinámico (como dice la documentación) `const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));`

Comment: En el caso de modificar la opción `type` en el archivo `package.json` recuerda entonces que todos los paquetes van a ser tratados por defecto como paquetes ES2015+. Si estás seguro de que está bien para tí entonces no hay problema